# How to create a colored transparent layer without using opacity

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, layers, transparency

I would like to create a transparent layer in pure color in PSD or AI. Using the opacity just washes the color out. I have done it before just can't remember how. It can be reproduced in HTML5 but I want to use in the adobe system.

Comment: Do you have an image of what you are trying to achieve? I have no clue what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

Using layers blending modes?

This image from [unsplash.com](https://unsplash.com/photos/R9piMYtKans) shows four different fillings whit a yellow solid color layer on top.

[image: blending mod]

Comment: Mind reading powers to the max! :D

Comment: I'm increasing my psychology skills in this site ‍

Comment: @thundereux: so this answers your question?

Comment: I dont remember the way I did it as Ive been away from Adobe for quite along time.. but I remember the layer could retain its solid color and still be transparent...